# unresolved external symbol Direct3DCreate9Ex

Tags: lnk2001

## How can I solve this problem?

## unresolved external symbol Direct3DCreate9Ex[text](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1126951774427816098/1129305078419951687/image.png)

I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.

I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.

I try to resolve this issue.

I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.
I try to resolve this issue.
v
vI try to resolve this issue.

I try to resolve this issue.v
I try to resolve this issue.